# MATLAB -Exponential (exp2) curve fitting function not giving the same output as the plot graph when using the fit values in the original equation

Tags: curve-fitting, exponential

my brain is pickled with this one. Below are the two graphs I have plotted with exp2 function. The points do not match the curve, and this is ultimately changing my entire answer, as it is giving the wrong values out, and I cannot understand why? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7v1No.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWzgf.jpg)

Here is the code I am using, both graphs plot a concentration against time, but yet give different results:

> CH4_fit = fit(Res_time, CH4_exp, 'exp2');  CH4_coeff =
>   coeffvalues(CH4_fit);
>   %Co-efficient values for exponential fitting CH4_pred
>   =(CH4_coeff(1)*exp(CH4_coeff(2)*Res_time)) + ...
>       (CH4_coeff(3)*exp(CH4_coeff(4)*Res_time)); plot(Res_time,CH4_exp, Res_time, CH4_pred);

Can I just added that the exact same data was run on different computers, and it gave the same equation co-efficients exactly (to 4.dp) and the same times, but yet still outputs different concentrations on my version? I have the R2018b, and I have just used default settings (don't know how to change anything, so I definitely haven't).